# How to host a Blogger.com blog on my domain's directory?

Tags: blogger, domain

How can I host a Blogger blog on my domain's directory?

For example **domain.com/blog**, instead of blog.domain.com or blog.com.

I have looked everywhere but it seems for Blogger it is only possible to host on the main domain or on a sub-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you are correct when mentioning that:

> ...it seems for Blogger it is only possible to host on the main domain or on a sub-domain.

To do it otherwise it would require an edit to **their** .htaccess file or **their** database which is most unlikely to happen.
Changing the CNAME records can only give you a main domain or sub-domain at the very best.

If you look around though, you may find some possibly outdated as well as not so reliable solutions that you could try.